# password validation breaks in IE11 using Jquery Validator

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-11

I'm having an interesting problem with IE11 and the [Jquery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). it starts with the same issue happening on both input type="email" and input type="password" - it seems that having any input BESIDES text brings up the default error message `Please enter a value that is greater or equal to undefined`.

So, changing the input type from email to text worked in the first instance, but I can't change the password type to text - I don't want the password to show up...

I have no idea why this is happening, or where the undefined variable is coming from - or even how to find out. Any suggestions?

code below:

```
$.validator.addMethod("valid_pass", function(value, element, regexpr) {
                    return this.optional(element) || regexpr.test(value);
                }, "Your password must be between 8-15 characters and contain at least 1 number.");

$("#element1").validate({
                    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
                         label.appendTo(element.parent('td').siblings('td'));
                    },
                    rules: {

                        password: { required: true, valid_pass: /^(?=.*\d).{8,15}$/ },
                        password2: { required: true, equalTo: "#password" }
                        },
                    messages: {

                        password: { required: "Create a password." },
                        password2: { 
                            required: "Re-enter your password.", 
                            equalTo: "Your passwords do not match." 
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and

```
<tr>
                            <td class="align-right"> Password: <a class="tooltip ml5" title="Password must be between 8-15 characters &amp; include at least 1 number">(?)</a></td>
                            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="15" tabindex="9"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="align-right"> Confirm password: </td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password2" maxlength="15" tabindex="10"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mistake, I found a solution that fixes the symptom, but NOT where it came from...

It seems that "min", "max", and "step" are added to inputs - either by the validator itself(?), or by browsers (it seems IE11 does this, as well as safari 7.0.1 on a mac). and not just password inputs - it did it on email inputs, and regular old text inputs, as well as checkboxes. Why? Only the browser gods know. To counteract this, I'm using Jquery, and running the following code to remove min,max, and step:

```
$('input, radio, textarea,select, checkbox').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('min max step');
});
```

As the last script i'm running inside $(document).ready

Without removing them, since min, max and step are attributes of the range input, the validator thinks this is a range input, and tries calculating it as a number...

Removing those attributes fixes it, and the problem is magically fixed. weird, but works..

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same javascript error messages in all IE version using jQuery.Validation. I installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.validation and solved my problems.